# Loading CSV to MySQL with odo and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, odo, datashape

I'm using odo to write a CSV file to a MySQL table.

```
uri = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@database/schema::table'
odo('data.csv', uri)
```

When I do not specify a [datashape](https://odo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datashape.html#datashape-and-odo), the MySQL table gets created with all string columns as TEXT and all integer columns as BIGINT(20).  So, I tried the following datashape, and got the errors below:

```
dshape = '{} * {{ \
    ID: 10 * string, \
    FOO: float16, \
    URL: 175 * var * string, \
    PRICE: uint32, \
    BAR: int8, \
}}'.format(num_rows)
uri = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@database/schema::table'
odo('data.csv', uri, dshape=dshape)
```

> NotImplementedError: No SQLAlchemy dtype match for datashape: var
>
> NotImplementedError: No SQLAlchemy dtype match for datashape: float16
>
> NotImplementedError: No SQLAlchemy dtype match for datashape: uint32
>
> NotImplementedError: No SQLAlchemy dtype match for datashape: int8

Ideally, I would be able to have int8 map to TINYINT, 175 * var * string map to VARCHAR(175), and 10 * string map to CHAR(10) for example, but it appears that SQLAlchemy does not support this.  I settled and set all my data types to int32 or float32 and my removed the var designation from my string types.

```
dshape = '{} * {{ \
    ID: 10 * string, \
    FOO: float32, \
    URL: 175 * string, \
    PRICE: int32, \
    BAR: int32, \
}}'.format(num_rows)
uri = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@database/schema::table'
odo('data.csv', uri, dshape=dshape)
```

This maps the int32 to INT(11) and float32 to DOUBLE.  I can live with this. But I cannot accept that all of my string columns are still written as TEXT on MySQL.

**How must I change my datashape to get CHAR and VARCHAR datatypes in MySQL?**

Answer (score -3):

you can try using pandas and sqlalchemy to achieve the same

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://username:password@host:port/database', echo=False)

#read csv into Dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

#write csv into Sql
df.to_sql('Table_Name', con=engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

It will read **data.csv** file and put it into **Table_Name** in your database

Comment: I started out using pandas, but found it to be highly inefficient. This article explains why not to use pandas to load a CSV into MySQL: http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/perf.html so I am avoiding that option if I can.